# Extracting counts by group and total counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a first select :

```
select count(id) from table_user group by idProfile
```

And the second select

```
select count(id) from table_user
```

How can I join the two select ?

because at least I need to know the portion of user with profile.

ex :

| id | idProfile |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 |

Expected result :

| nbProfileByIdProfile | nbTotalProfile | IdProfile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 8 | 1 |
| 3 | 8 | 2 |
| 1 | 8 | 3 |

Comment: By join them, do you mean get the same results in the same query? You don't need a `JOIN` for that

Comment: What is your expected result? To have an additional row with the total (which wouldn't be Join-like, but a Union-like), or for every row to also have the total (which would be Join-like).

Comment: select count( * ) over() as total, count( * ) over(partition by idProfile), idProfile from table_user

Comment: potentially with distinct or group by, if you want to have unique rows

Comment: @siggemannen I wanted this thank you can you post it

Answer (score 3):

Do `sum over` on the your current query's result:

```
select nbProfileByIdProfile, sum(nbProfileByIdProfile) over (), IdProfile
from (
  select count(id) nbProfileByIdProfile, IdProfile
  from table_user
  group by idProfile
) dt
```

Or, as suggested by @lemon - nest count(id) inside sum:

```
select count(id) nbProfileByIdProfile, sum(count(id)) over (), IdProfile
from table_user
group by idProfile
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/uZeeMwHf

Comment: You don't need a subquery, you can nest count(id) inside sum.

Comment: @lemon, thanks for the tip. (I never remember which dbms:s that support that.) I'll add that one to the answer.